# Visual Studio Code not finding Subscription for Azure Function Upload

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am evaluating Microsoft Azure. In particular I am interested in Azure Functions.

On my Azure account I get this:
[image]

But when I try and upload an Azure Function form Studio Code, I get this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I can get out of this loop and upload and tryout Azure Functions?

I would have thought that this functionality would be basic stuff. So I'm convinced I must be doing something wrong, or is it that Microsoft are still catching up with AWS and Google?

Comment: Have you signed into Azure in VS code? In the command palette fine Azure: Sign In.

Comment: How do I open the command palette? In the command console entering Azure: Sign In, results in: Azure: : The term 'Azure:' is not recognized as ....

Comment: Have you installed the Azure extensions? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-node-azure-pack

Comment: Logging into Azure via the command palette worked (ctrl + shift + p). Looks like the pretend login via Visual Studio Code is a smoke and mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think you did not install `Azure Functions extension`, The Azure Functions extension is included with the the Azure Tools extension pack, if you want to install it, you can visit this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions).

Once you've installed the Azure extension, sign into your Azure account by navigating to the Azure explorer, select Sign in to Azure, and follow the prompts.

[image]

For more details, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01#visual-studio-code-python-and-the-azure-functions-extension).

Comment: I think this could be right. I did do this before, and VSC hands over to a browser to do the sign in part, and then hands back. But it must have lost the connection. I hard signed in via the command palette, and now things seem to be working as expected.

Thanks for the reply tho.

Onwards with the evaluation...